# Youtube video playing after i closed inner window

Tags: webview, youtube, javafx

I open a Youtube video in WebView. WebView is in the inner window.

```
    Window w = new Window("My MDI Window");
    w.setPrefSize(640, 480);

    final WebView webview = new WebView();
    webview.getEngine().load(
            "http://www.youtube.com/embed/utUPth77L_o?autoplay=1");
    webview.setPrefSize(640, 390);

    w.getLeftIcons().add(new CloseIcon(w));
    w.getRightIcons().add(new MinimizeIcon(w));
    w.getContentPane().getChildren().add(webview);
    pane.getChildren().add(w);
```

After closing window, i hear audio.
How can i close "video", when i closing inner window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `destroy` functionality for `WebEngine`. The only workaround which I have found so far for this is to use

```
webView.getEngine().load(null);
```